# Reading multilined cell of csv file from java

Tags: java, csv

I have an CSV file which I want to read in Java, Problem is that my CSV file contains multi-lined cell, for example this is an entry of my CSV file

```
"[Not Before]
  25-01-2011 05:30:00

[Not After]
  16-03-2014 05:29:59

","Valid","Signature verified","C:\Users\ngoel\Desktop\drivers\x64\aksclass.sys"
```

This is only one line of my CSV file

Comment: Use the logic implied by the format: if a cell begins with a double quote, read until you find aonther unescaped double quote...

Comment: What will be your line separator?

Comment: I'm pretty sure JCSV will read your file easily. http://code.google.com/p/jcsv/

Comment: `csv` is effectively a text file with delimiter to separate columns. Why can't you use a regular `FileReader` to read it?

Comment: But there are double quotes in the data too, so doblu coutes cant be used, i think  @ppeterka

Comment: @R.J my csv data is quite complex  it itself has comma doublequotes , so i am not able to read multi lined attribute

Comment: The double quotes at the beginnign and end of a CSV cell are _not considered to be part of the cell content_ itself. And a cell containing a double quote has to be escaped too, usually by doubling of the double quotes, e.g. `"` -> `""` inside the quote-enclosed string

Comment: @KugathasanAbimaran there is no as such line seperator as \n is used for multi line cell values,,, each row has 3 entries out of which 2 are single valued rest are multi valued

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem although in this case it was the creation of CSVs that could handle multi-line cell values.

The code I was replacing had been hand-crafted by another developer with some other oddities in parsing the input fields also in place.

I opted to replace this code by using an open source library http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/ as this handled multi-line and other common parsing issues for me through a fairly simple API which is has good simple examples and docs.